# how to print each element of an array in x86-64 at&t syntax?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-64

Hope all is well.

I am trying to loop over each element of an array and printing each element but cannot find the right way. I have been searching for multiple hours now.

So far I have this code:

```
    .section .data

array:
    .quad 1,2,3,4,5
    .section .text
    
    .globl main
    
main:
    leaq array(%rip), %rcx
    movq $0, %rsi
    jmp test

body:
    
    movq (%rcx, %rsi, 8), %rdi
    callq print_int
    incq %rsi
    jmp test

test:
    cmpq $5, %rsi
    jne body
    je exit

exit:
    movq $3, %rdi
    callq print_int
```

But I get a segmentation fault. The closest I have gotten is printing `13`:

```
    .section .data

array:
    .quad 1,2,3,4,5
    .section .text
    
    .globl main
    
main:
    leaq array(%rip), %rcx
    movq $0, %rsi

loop:
    movq (%rcx, %rsi, 8), %rax
    movq %rax, %rdi
    callq print_int
    addq $1, %rsi
    cmpq $5, %rsi
    je loop
    jmp exit

exit:
    movq $3, %rdi
    callq print_int
```

`print_int` is a function I am using from a compiler runtime.

I am compiling with `gcc`: `gcc -g runtime.o program.s`.

Any help will be appeaciated. thanks

The duplicate question doesn’t answer my question because I’m not asking about functional calls. I want to print the elements of an array

Comment: Can you provide *any* details about this segmentation fault?

Comment: Presumably `print_int` follows the normal calling convention, so it doesn't preserve RCX or RSI.  Use call-preserved regs like RBX and R15 for your loop variables.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks. So the my first example looks right except for the registers? Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, correct but clunky.  The `jmp test` is a no-op, execution will already go to the next instruction regardless of labels *unless* you jump.  Same for the `je exit`, the `jne body` already fell through, so you don't need a jump to go anywhere else.  I'd recommend looking at optimized compiler output for a loop that calls a function on every element of an array, e.g. on https://godbolt.org/ (and see [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116))

Comment: Your question is a duplicate because you're assuming RCX and RSI will still have the same values after `call print_int`.  And the problem is that they won't, like that Q&A explains.  If you're not familiar with the concept of call-clobbered registers, see [What are callee and caller saved registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178078)

Comment: There are tons of duplicates of your exact problem, of loops that break because function calls clobber registers.  e.g. [Segment fault Assembly NASM on print array values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63548836) / [Assembly infinite loop with printf function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39254931) / [Is function call messing with other registers than %rax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52460450) (most of the "linked questions" from the Linux function-call Q&A)

Comment: @PeterCordes oh ok I see. But yea I used those registers you told me and it worked; thank you so much! One quick question. what does it mean "..normal calling convention, so it doesnt preserve rcx or rsi"? what are call-preserved regs? thanks

Comment: The normal calling convention (on non-Windows) is the one documented in the x86-64 System V ABI.  In hand-written asm, some functions might use a custom calling convention, like preserving all registers.  As for call-preserved regs, like I wrote 2 comments ago, if you aren't familiar with the term and concept, see [What are callee and caller saved registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178078)